# Sort an array on month order

Tags: javascript

I want to sort this array, According to the month `Jan, feb, march` and so on.
using JavaScript on front-end

```
[[["February",17],["January",30],["March",40],["April",40],["May",50],["June",60]]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** with a month order mapping object

```js
var data = [
  ["June", 60],
  ["February", 17],
  ["January", 30],
  ["March", 40],
  ["April", 40],
  ["May", 50]
];
// object which holds the order value of the month
var monthNames = {
  "January": 1,
  "February": 2,
  "March": 3,
  "April": 4,
  "May": 5,
  "June": 6,
  "July": 7,
  "August": 8,
  "September": 9,
  "October": 10,
  "November": 11,
  "December": 12
};

// sort the data array
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  // sort based on the value in the monthNames object
  return monthNames[a[0]] - monthNames[b[0]];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 3) + '</pre>')
```

Comment: Thank You so much...its nice and clean

Comment: @NikitPatel : glad to help :)

Comment: Could be simplified to a simple month array and `return monthNames.indexOf(a[0]) - monthNames.indexOf(b[0]);`

Comment: @mplungjan ... i think, While comparing with property accessor indexOf method would be slower