# How to filter array of object by current month in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using laravel and it's has created_at field timestamp.

I want to sort the array of objects using the current month.

My array looks like this

```
var arr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "roi": 90,
  "sport": "Biatlon",
  "created_at": "2017-12-29 11:42:40",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "iamsadek",
    "profilePic": "90TyP1Rkn2WI4T5VQmqmJJPB5cAY8BMrUim1WJT0.png"
  }
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "user_id": 2,
  "roi": 30,
  "sport": "Atletika",
  "created_at": "2018-01-10 22:20:06",
  "user": {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "hkmsadek",
    "profilePic": "pic.png"
  }
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "user_id": 5,
  "roi": 10,
  "sport": "Biatlon",
  "created_at": "2018-01-10 17:11:45",
  "user": {
    "id": 5,
    "userName": "deil",
    "profilePic": "L8KIW0gXXmi5QALnAHjksCdg4tcUK9cx5jn84nrk.jpeg"
  }
}]
```

I want to sort this array by current month.

Please help with any clue. I am currently trying to use lodash but it doesn't provide anything like this.

Comment: can't you that inside query itself?

Comment: Yes I can, but it has many sorting options so I completed other sorting options using js. I don't want to hit database everytime and also js is way too fast. :)

Comment: Try something like this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37167184/1005741 It should help

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by current month"?

Comment: Do you mean "filter" instead of "sort"?

Comment: Yes "filter" is the correct word!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own compare method and call sort function from array.

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.created_at < b.created_at)
    return -1;
  if (a.created_at > b.created_at)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

    yourArray.sort(compare);

yourArray.sort(compare);
```

Comment: Nope, this will only return the order of date and it won't restrict by month. :(

Comment: Hi, you can use current month instead of b.created_at when comparing. For that you have to get current month from current date. See it may help you.

Comment: @sadek What do you mean by "restrict"? Sorting doesn't restrict anything, it just reorders it.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash's [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#orderBy) method and [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) you could order the collection with respect to `created_at`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var payload = [{
      "id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "roi": 90,
      "sport": "Biatlon",
      "created_at": "2017-12-29 11:42:40",
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "iamsadek",
        "profilePic": "90TyP1Rkn2WI4T5VQmqmJJPB5cAY8BMrUim1WJT0.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "user_id": 2,
      "roi": 30,
      "sport": "Atletika",
      "created_at": "2018-01-10 22:20:06",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "userName": "hkmsadek",
        "profilePic": "pic.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "user_id": 5,
      "roi": 10,
      "sport": "Biatlon",
      "created_at": "2018-01-10 17:11:45",
      "user": {
        "id": 5,
        "userName": "deil",
        "profilePic": "L8KIW0gXXmi5QALnAHjksCdg4tcUK9cx5jn84nrk.jpeg"
      }
    }
  ];

  var sorted = _.orderBy(payload, function(item) {
    return moment(item.created_at, 'Y-M-D H:m:s').unix();
  }, 'desc');

  console.log(sorted);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```