# How to sort a Month Array in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am currently working in a sales application that shows a list of appointments for a month using `SectionList`. The datasource to the `SectionList` would look something similar to,

`var sectionList = [{
key: month
value: appointmentData
}]`;

Now, I want to sort this Month array in the order of their real occurrence.

Current Output:

```
[Jan, Apr, Feb, Mar, Sep, May, Dec, July, Nov, June, Oct, Aug]
```

Expected Output:

```
[Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, June, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec];
```

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: `sortFunction(a,b) { return monthsArr.indexOf(a.month) - monthsArr.indexOf(b.month) }`

Comment: Can you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167102/sort-an-array-on-month-order ?