# filter array of objects by object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Trying to filter an array of objects by start and end object values.

```
start = "Feb-2015"
end = "Jul-2015"

result = array.sort(2,7);
```

have tried this but I have dates, I will be not knowing the index of it.
    array = [
      {
        "date": "Jan-2015"
      },
      {
        "date": "Feb-2015"
      },
      {
        "date": "Mar-2015"
      },
      {
        "date": "Apr-2015"
      },
      {    "date": "May-2015"
      },
      {,
        "date": "Jun-2015"
      },
      {    "date": "Jul-2015"
      },
      {
        "date": "Aug-2015"
      }
    ]

expected output:-

```
result = [
      {
        "date": "Feb-2015"
      },
      {
        "date": "Mar-2015"
      },
      {
        "date": "Apr-2015"
      },
      {    "date": "May-2015"
      },
      {,
        "date": "Jun-2015"
      },
      { 
        "date": "Jul-2015"
      }
]
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167102/sort-an-array-on-month-order

Comment: filter = data.filter(function(d){
 var date = new Date(d.metric_name);

 return (date >= new Date(start) && date <= new Date(end))
})

Answer (score 0):

Use below.

```js
array = [{
    "date": "Jan-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "Aug-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "Apr-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "May-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jun-2015"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jul-2015"
  }

];

//filter
sort = (arr, start, end) => {
  let arrayFiltered = arr.filter((obj) => {
    obj.dateObj = new Date(obj.date.substring(0, 3) + obj.date.substring(4, 8));

    return (obj.dateObj.getMonth() + 1) >= start && (obj.dateObj.getMonth() + 1) <= end;
  });

  console.log(arrayFiltered.sort(obj => obj.dateObj));
};

sort(array, 2, 7);
```

**Output**

```
[{
  "date": "Feb-2015",
  "dateObj": "2015-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  "date": "Mar-2015",
  "dateObj": "2015-02-28T18:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  "date": "Apr-2015",
  "dateObj": "2015-03-31T18:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  "date": "May-2015",
  "dateObj": "2015-04-30T18:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  "date": "Jun-2015",
  "dateObj": "2015-05-31T18:30:00.000Z"
}, {
  "date": "Jul-2015",
  "dateObj": "2015-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"
}]
```

Comment: filter = data.filter(function(d){
 var date = new Date(d.metric_name);

 return (date >= new Date(start) && date <= new Date(end))
})

Comment: this will do ty :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{"date":"Jan-2018"},{"date":"Feb-2015"},{"date":"Mar-2015"},{"date":"Apr-2015"},{"date":"May-2015"},{"date":"Jun-2015"},{"date":"Jul-2015"},{"date":"Aug-2015"}];

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)}));
```